# Find the maximum safe allowable bending moment.

Tags: physics

A rolled steel universal I-section beam with a serial size of $406\times178$ has a mass of $60$kg/m. What is the maximum safe allowable bending moment this beam can sustain,given that the maximum allowable bending stress in tension and compression must not exceed $165$N/mm$^2$.

I have this problem and I have no Idea to solve this.Please kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this on the [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) site instead.

Comment: @DavidMitra thank you.